# Push a UIImageView with another UIImageView, possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to pan a UIImageView and when it intersects with the frame of another UIImageView, have that other UIImageView be pushed around by the other UIImageView without just passing over it? I hope that makes sense!

If it is possible, could you give me some ideas on how I'd go about implementing this?

I imagine it would go something like...

If frame intersects frame from  left or right on the x/y axis, have the other frame move in that same direction with same distance as the pushing frame. While that logic somewhat makes sense to me, I'm not sure how I'd implement that in code.

I'd really appreciate any advice you can offer.

Comment: Yeah... I'm basically looking for a way to use one UIImageView to slide another one to the left or right depending on the direction the pan gesture is moving.

Comment: You mean when the user swipes, the current image should be pushed to left by the next image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're only concerned with left / right panning...

Let's assume you have 2 UIImageViews, a & b, as subviews of some other UIView and defined as class members of some class.

You can get help detecting panning gestures (dragging touches) on each of these views by creating instances of UIPanGestureRecognizer and adding them to each UIImageView using method addGestureRecognizer:

When creating each UIPanGestureRecognizer, you need to designate a selector to receive the gesture events. Let say it's called didMove:

Now, some sample code:

```
- (void) didMove:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    UIView* view = [recognizer view];

    // Remember our UIImageViews are class members called, a & b
    //
    UIView* otherView = view == a ? b : a;    

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegin 
        || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        // Moving left will have a negative x, moving right positive
        //
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:view.superview];
        view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x + translation.x, view.center.y);

        // Reset so we always track the translation from the current view position
        //
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view.superview];

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view.frame, otherView.frame)) {
            // Translate by the same number of points to keep views in sync
            //
            otherView.center = CGPointMake(otherView.center.x + translation.x, otherView.center.y);
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be exactly what you need, but it should give you a good idea how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd better use something like Cocos2D with it's sprites, intersections and some basic physics...

Comment: Without the use of Cocos2D, this feature would be really difficult to implement?

Comment: A lot of calculations and custom animation dirty work, that's all. Not something overwhelming thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

First, Create an UIImageView and assign an UIImage to it.

Second, When the user swipes or makes any gesture just change the coordinates of the card by setting its frame again.

Since u want the card to slide away, you have to change the x coordinate to a negative value such that it slides off from the view.

The above said code of reframing the imageview should be given within a UIView setAnimation group of methods...with a required delay.

To achieve the push effect have a method called within the the same animation block of codes which creates a new imageview (having same name as that of first imageview) and keep it out of the view. That is beyond the width of the screen. (dont forget to release the card which was pushes away previously)

Then subsequently again make a new frame for this imageview such that it appears in the centre of the screen....When above three steps of code are put within the animation block of code for UIView or UIImageView with a delay time , u will achieve the required effect.

Hope this helps....

happy coding....